# Narrowing a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I am attempting to write a "Task" system for a game that can take in generic "GameTasks" with Payloads, however I think I am having a problem with covariance.

This is the function that adds the task to the repository

```
   internal void AddTask(IGameTask<IPayload> task)       
    {
        Tasks.Add(task);
        Broker.Instance.Publish(new TaskAdded(task));

    }
```

The repository is currently just a list

```
public List<IGameTask<IPayload>> Tasks { get; } = new();
```

This is the task and payload I am attempting to add

```
public interface IBuildTaskPayload : IPayload
{
    public float ContributeAmount { get; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Created when a building is placed
/// </summary>
public class BuildTask : IGameTask<IBuildTaskPayload>
{
    ...

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public TaskStatus UpdateTask(IBuildTaskPayload updatePayload)
    {
        Progress += updatePayload.ContributeAmount;
        return Progress >= 100 ? TaskStatus.Finished : TaskStatus.Executing;

    }

 }
```

And attempting to add it to the repository

```
TaskRepository.Instance.AddTask(new BuildTask(construction));
```

This last part fails, as BuildTask cannot be cast to IGameTask. Why is this? And how would I go about achieving this correctly?

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) ... but you cannot have both at the same time

Comment: Can you show the def of `IGameTask<IPayload>`

Answer (score 0):

You make have to remove the generics from `IGameTask<IPayLoad>`

You don't  show the definition, but to remove the generic parameter you do something like this

```
public interface IGameTask
{
    IPayLoad PayLoad { get; }
}
```

This solves the problem that you have which stems from the fact that each implementation of `IGameTask<>` is a different type.

---

For example

```
public interface IPayLoad { }
public interface IGameTask
{
    IPayLoad PayLoad { get; }
}

public class BuildingAssets : IPayLoad
{
}

public class BuildTask : IGameTask
{
    public BuildingAssets PayLoad { get; }
    IPayLoad IGameTask.PayLoad { get => PayLoad; }
}
```

to be used as

```
List<IGameTask> tasks = new List<IGameTask>();
// fill list

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    if (task is BuildTask build)
    {
        BuildingAssets assets = build.PayLoad;
    }
}
```